# Microsoft SQL Server : how to filter out results of a 2nd query from the first query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have data that looks like this:

[image: Data example]

I have some records that are retired and some that are active. The problem is some of my records have both retired and active rows. I only want records that do not have an active row.

So in this example despite the fact that Greg has 2 retired rows. The fact that one of his rows is active would disqualify him. Tommy on the other hand only has 1 row and it is retired. He doesn't have an active row.

The query would return only Tommy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your definition, employee's could just be defined by name. Then you can use EXISTS. ie:

```
select * from myTable t1
where Status = 'RETIRED' and 
     not exists (
   select * from myTable t2 
   where t1.EmployeeName = t2.employeeName and t2.Status = 'ACTIVE');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE Status = 'RETIRED'
AND [Employee Name] NOT IN -- Assumes that Employee Name is a unique key
(
SELECT [Employee Name] FROM myTable 
WHERE Status = 'ACTIVE'
)
```